# Netbeans + tomcat on Ubuntu

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, ubuntu

I migrated to Ubuntu from windows recently and am going to use Netbeans on it now. I have installed Netbeans using synaptic but I do not see services option in tools tab.

Will i have to install Tomcat separately ?

Comment: seemed like a very easy question to me....no answer yet...

Answer (score 5):

To enable the ***Servers*** item, go  **Tools > Plugins** and install the ***Java Web Applications*** plugin (or even the whole *Java Web and EE* category) first.

Then, to integrate NetBeans with Tomcat, follow [these instructions](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansAndWebStack#Tomcat_Web_Server).

Note that **Services** is ***not*** in the **Tools** menu, it's near the **Projects** tab:

[image]

You can also add a server from **Tools > Servers**.

And yes, you'll have to install Tomcat separately (and I warmly recommend to get a regular archive from [Tomcat's website](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) and to unzip it in your home directory i.e. don't use the packaged version that you can install from Synaptic for development).

Comment: I am using NetBeans 6.7.1 and in it tool> Services is not there although there is Window>services

Comment: @AJ As I wrote, **Services** is **not** under the **Tools** menu (but yes, if you closed it, you can find it back from the **Window** menu).

Comment: Yes I understand but in services tab I am not getting add server as an option. There is just one thing  - HUDSUN BUILDERS.

Comment: @AJ I've updated my answer, you need to install a plugin first (see the top of my answer).